# Inject service/object into controller after an asynchronous (ajax) call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently globalizing a website developed with both ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS. For the JS part I am using [angular-localization](http://doshprompt.github.io/angular-localization/) to load the resource bundles.

Right now I have a controller like this:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = "Hello World!";
}]);
```

With ngLocalize I can use the locale service, getting the resource string in a callback:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'locale', function($scope, locale) {
  locale.ready('ResourceFile').then(function() {
    $scope.msg = locale.getString('ResourceFile.HelloWorld');
  });
}]);
```

The problem is that I have to translate hundreds of strings and introducing a callback makes it hard to review the code, and sometimes forces me to change the controller logic (e.g: when I need the resource string inside a function which return a message to the caller). I would like to call locale.getString() directly, without a callback:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'locale', function($scope, locale) {
    $scope.msg = locale.getString('ResourceFile.HelloWorld');
}]);
```

Maybe the locale.ready() promise could be called before the controller is initialized, thus preloading the resource files inside the locale service.

Please keep in mind that I am dealing with legacy code and the website is not a single page application, so I cannot use routeProvider / resolve is (apparently) not an option here.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could write a filter to do the local.getString
thus eliminating the need for passing in the string each time

Comment: @Teliren Thank you for your comment. Can you be more specific about your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of struggling I finally found a more suited solution for my case (edit: there's a better solution - see below).

It involves: 1) Injecting the ngLocalize service into a dummyApp and 2) bootstrap the "real" app manually. I suspect that this code can be improved (a lot) but at least it solves my problem for now:

```
var dummyApp = angular.module('dummyApp', ['ngLocalize', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies'])
  .value('localeSupported', ['en-US', 'pt-BR'])
  .value('localeConf', {...);

var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngCookies']);

var RESOURCES_TO_LOAD = ['Common'];
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng", "dummyApp"]);
  var locale = initInjector.get("locale");

  locale.ready(RESOURCES_TO_LOAD).then(function () { 
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['sampleApp']);
  });
});
```

The controller logic is as follows:

```
// controller-specific code
var RESOURCES_TO_LOAD = ['Common', 'MyResource1', 'MyResource2'];
sampleApp.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', 'locale', function ($scope, locale) {
    $scope.msg = locale.getString('MyResource1.Value1');
}]);
```

**EDIT: there's a much simpler solution**

```
sampleApp.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', 'locale', function ($scope, locale) {
  locale.ready(['Common', 'MyResource1', 'MyResource2']).then(function() {
    $scope.msg = locale.getString('MyResource1.Value1');
  });
});
```

It is actually so simple that I'm ashamed I never thought of it before

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to solve this would be using the `resolve` feature from ng-route or ui-router, as the views/controllers are not instantiated until the data from the `resolve` is available.

You can do the same thing, albeit in a less elegant way:

```
<div ng-if="dataIsAvailable>
  <div ng-controller="MyController"></div>
</div>
```

In the above, `MyController` won't be instantiated until the expression in the `ng-if` is true.

Now you need to pre-load your resource files and make their data available to other application components. Simple example:

```
angular.factory('MyLocaleService', function(locale) {

  var  MyLocaleService = function() {};
  var localeData = {};

  MyLocaleService.prototype.loadResource = function() {
    locale.ready('ResourceFile').then(function() {
      // get the data from the resource file and iterate over it to
      // store the data in a local var... For this example only doing
      // a simple assignment
      localeData['myString'] = locale.getString('myString');
    });
  }

  MyLocaleService.prototype.getString = function(string) {
    return localeData[string];
  }

  return new MyLocaleService();
});
```

**Putting it all together**:

When your app starts, pre-load the URL's (MyLocaleService.loadResource()). Defer instantiation of the views/controllers until the data is available using `ng-if` or something similar. Inject `MyLocaleService` into your controllers and use it to fetch the resource bundle strings.

Comment: This is an acceptable solution to my problem, I will have to change the markup of dozens of pages, but it is better than changing dozens of controllers to use the resolve feature, since it is a legacy app. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the documentation ngLocalize already has a filter. 
so in the html you could do something like

```
<span>{{ 'Resourcefile.HelloWorld' | i18n }}</span>
```

Or

```
<span>{{ msg | i18n}}<span>
```

Then your controller could look like

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) { 
        $scope.msg = 'ResourceFile.HelloWorld';
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunately, I need to use the translated string in more complex use cases. e.g: notifyService.error(locale.getString(...)); I should have been clearer about that in my question, sorry.